# Div won't fill parent div

Tags: html, css

This seems to be asked a lot, but any of the fixes I've found here (flexbox, table cell display, etc) don't seem to fully fill. I'm looking to have a top bar at the top, bottom bar at the bottom, and a middle area that at least makes the three of them fill the page (and is split in the middle). Here's a basic layout:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

#main {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

#topBar {
  color: #0A2C73;
  height: 80px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #0A2C73;
}

#middle {
  height: auto;
}

#middle>div {
  display: inline-block;
}

#middle #leftSide {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 140px;
  border-right: 5px solid #0A2C73;
}

#bottom {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="topBar">
    top
  </div>
  <div id="middle">
    <div id="leftSide">
      left
    </div>
    <div id="rightSide">
      right
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

and [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/b2o7teuj/)

But none of the items I've found seem to work, either the middle overlaps the top, or the height is too tall, etc. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't believe it should be marked as a duplicate, or at the very least not with the post linked. That post asks about fixed header and footer, this one doesn't. Also, although there are solutions that could work for both with minimal adjustment, the accepted answer for the linked post is outdated and wouldn't really work for the problem in this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With css grid you can do something like this:

```css
body { margin: 0 }

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows:    60px 1fr 60px;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(300px, 1fr) 3fr;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.top, .bottom {
  background-color: #BAD;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.content {
  background-color: #BADA55;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #A55;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: That works - checking compatability, it seems new browsers only, but it's good for the demo, thank you.

Comment: The center div is kind of necessary and defeats the purpose of using CSS grid. This same example only requires you use a grid for the middle, the rest flows like a normal page and makes grid's use redundant.

Comment: @Laif Sorry, I thing I don't understand what you mean. You could do the same with flexbox, sure, is that what you mean? I prefer to use grid for overall page structure even if it's that simple, because it make it easier to modify and extend if needed.

Comment: @HenriqueErzinger I just mean that you didn't real make use of it to accomplish what he wanted in terms of the split middle div. Having a filler div there isn't as efficient as having two divs be formatted by the already established grid. Check out my answer below to see what I mean

Comment: @Laif Oh, I see. I didn't really use his snippet as a reference, and he didn't mention sidebars in the question itself, so I focused on the middle div filling up the space, which is what he asked about. I'll update the snippet, since my approach is slightly different from yours.

Comment: No reason to change your answer haha, its valid @HenriqueErzinger

Comment: Done it already :) Thanks for the heads up anyway

Answer (score 2):

No reason you couldn't do this with grid

```css
    #main {
      display: grid;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #main > div{
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    #topBar {
      grid-column: 1 / 3;
      grid-row: 1;
     }
    #rightSide {
      grid-column: 2;
      grid-row: 2;
       
    }
    #leftSide {
      grid-column: 1;
      grid-row: 2;
    }
    #bottom {
      grid-column: 1 / 3;
      grid-row: 3;
    }
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <div id='topBar'>
  top
  </div>
  <div id='leftSide'>
  left
  </div>
  <div id='rightSide'>
  right
  </div>
  <div id='bottom'>
  bottom
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, very clear -

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox solution:

```
#main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

#middle {
    flex: 1;
}
```

You need to tell flex to utilize `#main` as a column cell, in which case, using the `flex: 1` setting on `#middle`, the middle section dynamically grows to fit the negative space. You also need to create that negative space by adding `min-height: 100vh` to your `#main` element.

I recommend flatting your DOM structure by removing `#main` and adding itsstyles to `body`.

In a previous answer, the commenter used classes. This is the recommended in best practice in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox makes quick work of it.

```css
    html,
    body {
        height: 150px; /* demo only */
        margin: 0px auto;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #main {
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background: orange;
    }

    #topBar {
        color: #0A2C73;
        height: 80px;
        border-bottom: 5px solid #0A2C73;
        background: pink;
    }

    #middle {
        background: lightgreen;
        flex-grow: 1;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    #middle>div {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #middle #leftSide {
        max-width: 140px;
        border-right: 5px solid #0A2C73;
    }

    #bottom {
        height: 20px;
        background: lightblue;
    }
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="topBar">
        top
    </div>
    
    <div id="middle">
        <p>middle</p>
        <p>middle</p>
        <p>middle</p>
        <p>middle</p>
        <p>middle</p>
        <p>middle</p>
        <p>middle</p>
        <p>middle</p>
        <p>middle</p>
        <p>middle</p>
        <p>middle</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="bottom">
        bottom
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
you need to add flex on #main and flex-grow:1 property on #middle.
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
#main {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
#topBar {
    color: #0A2C73;
    height:80px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #0A2C73;
}
#middle {
    height:auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
  #middle > div{
    display:inline-block;
  }
    #middle #leftSide {
        min-height: 100%;
        height:auto;
        max-width: 140px;
        border-right: 5px solid #0A2C73;
    }
#bottom{
    height:20px;
}
```

here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8km54zce/. I hope this is what you want.

Answer (score -4):

best practice

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">Left Site</div>
       <div class="col-md-6">Right Site</div>
   </div>
 <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">Middle</div>
   </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is this a "best practice"? It also appears as if your answer is based on Bootstrap, which the question isn't tagged with. It would be helpful if you explained your answer as well.

Comment: Also, it doesn't achieve what the op asked for.